# What's the error in this solution to a problem asking minimum steps to reach 1 given a number?

Tags: python-2.7, math, binary, numbers

I need to find the minimum required steps to reach 1 given a number, up to 9^309, and am using python 2.7 for this.

I'm only allowed three kinds of operations: add 1, subtract 1, and divide by 2 if number is even.

For the solution I used the following strategy:

1. convert number to binary form
2. While number is not equal to '1':

   - If end digit is 0 divide by 2
   - If end digit is 1 and second to last digit is also 1 add 1 (except for 3)
   - If end digit is 1 and second to last digit is 0 subtract 1

I used the following functions:

```
def compare_nums(n, pow_2_num):
    """Checks n >= pow_2_num. returns -1 if false, 0 if equal, or else 1"""
    if (n == pow_2_num):
        return (0)
    if (len(n) == len(pow_2_num)):
        return (1 if n > pow_2_num else -1)
    if (len(n) > len(pow_2_num)):
        return (1)
    return (-1)

def max_pow_2(n):
    """returns a positive integer x, such that n >= 2^x"""
    pow_2_num = 1
    x = 0
    while (True):
        pow_2_num *= 2
        res = compare_nums(n, str(pow_2_num))
        if res != -1:
            x += 1
        if res != 1:
            return x

def raise_2(pow_2):
    """returns 2^pow_2 as a string"""
    if (pow_2 == 0):
        return ('1')
    num = '1'
    for _ in range(pow_2):
        carry = 0
        temp = ''
        for i in range(len(num) - 1, -1, -1):
            prod = int(num[i]) * 2 + carry
            carry = prod // 10
            temp = str(prod % 10) + temp
        if carry:
            temp = str(carry) + temp
        num = temp
    return (num.lstrip('0'))

def sub_num(n, pow_2):
    """returns n - 2^pow_2 in string form"""
    num_pow_2 = raise_2(pow_2)
    l_len = len(n)
    r_len = len(num_pow_2)
    borrowed = 0
    ans = ''
    # subract digit by digit moving left starting from end
    for i in range(r_len):
        l_curr = int(n[l_len - 1 - i]) - borrowed
        r_curr = int(num_pow_2[r_len - 1 - i])
        if l_curr >= r_curr:
            borrowed = 0
        else:
            l_curr += 10
            borrowed = 1
        ans = str(l_curr - r_curr) + ans
    sub_index = l_len - r_len - 1  # index in n, just before start of subtraction
    if borrowed:
        # find index of first nonzero going left from sub_index(inclusive)
        for i in range(sub_index, -1, -1):
            if n[i] != '0':
                break
        ans = n[:i] + str(int(n[i]) - 1) + '9' * (sub_index - i) + ans
    else:
        ans = n[:sub_index + 1] + ans
    ans = ans.lstrip('0')
    return (ans if ans else '0')

def generate_x_i_list(n):
    """creates a list of two's exponents equaling n.
    for  n = 2^i + 2^j ... + 2^k, such that i, j,...,k >= 0,
    returns [i, j, ... k]"""
    x_i_list = []
    while (True):
        pow_2 = max_pow_2(n)
        x_i_list.append(pow_2)
        n = sub_num(n, pow_2)
        if n == '0':
            break
    return (x_i_list)

def to_binary(n):
    """converts n to base 2 representation"""
    if n == '0':
        return ('0')
    x_i_list = generate_x_i_list(n)
    binary_len = int(x_i_list[0]) + 1
    n_binary = [0 for i in range(binary_len)]
    for pow_2 in x_i_list:
        n_binary[binary_len - 1 - pow_2] = 1
    n_binary = [str(i) for i in n_binary]
    return (''.join(n_binary))

def solution(n):
    """returns minimum no. of steps required to reach 1 starting from n.
    allowed steps: add or subtract 1, and divide by 2 if n is even"""

    n_binary = to_binary(n)
    step_count = 0
    while (n_binary != '1'):
        if (n_binary[-1] == '0'):  # divide by 2
            while (n_binary[-1] == '0'):
                n_binary = n_binary[:-1]
                step_count += 1
        elif (n_binary[-1] == '1'):
            if (n_binary[-2] == '1' and len(n_binary) > 2):  # > 2 to avoid adding one to 3 (0b11) 
                # add 1: change 1's to 0's, starting from end until 0 is found and changed to 1.
                # If no 0 is found (check first) add 1 at start
                zero_exists = n_binary.count('0')
                if zero_exists:
                    zero_index = n_binary.rindex('0')
                    aftr_0 = '0' * (len(n_binary) - 1 - zero_index)
                    bfr_0 = n_binary[:zero_index]
                    n_binary = bfr_0 + '1' + aftr_0
                else:
                    n_binary = '1' + ('0' * len(n_binary))
            else:
                # subtract 1: change last 1 to 0
                n_binary = n_binary[:-1] + '0'
            step_count += 1
    return (step_count)
```

I've run the checker and the above solution is failing for half of the tests. (I have no access to see inputs). I've tried to test with many edge cases I can think of, but the function works for all so far.

But the checker passes for all tests when using this function from stackoverflow.

```
def stepCount(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 1:
        if n % 2 == 0:
            n = n // 2
        elif n == 3 or n % 4 == 1:
            n = n - 1
        else:
            n = n + 1
        count += 1
    return count
```

I have looked up, and also compared results from my implementation and the function that passed (with no. up to 10^6), but haven't figured out where the error is in my code.

What is causing the above solution (first one with helper functions) to fail for half of tests? OR

Which edge cases should I use to find the error?

Comment: Python 2.7 was officially killed off a number of years ago, is there a specific reason you _have_ to use 2.7 or can you just use the 3.x versions that everyone else currently uses? (Also, note that Python can already convert a number to binary form using `bin()`). That said, this is a _lot_ of code given that you're only allowed three operations, especially since you don't need a binary conversion, you can just work directly with the original number and use modulo to "check bits" as shown in that `stepCount` function. If you _do_ use binary: reverse it. Much easier to work with that way.

Comment: Maybe the checker is failing your code on performance rather than incorrect answers?

Comment: Why is your code so much more complicated than `stepCount`?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk
@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans@SimonGoater
I'm a beginner in coding and I wanted to know if there is an error in my functions, so that it could be a learning experience. Previously we did an exercise that didn't allow use of python functions for numbers exceeding python 2.7's plain int limit. And I wanted to apply those concepts here too, as an experiment.